# using external js to call aspx.cs function (on button click)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, external

I am trying to call an aspx.cs function using an external javascript when a button is clicked on.

Here is the aspx

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl ("~/Scripts/lookup.js") %>"></script>
</head>
<body>

        <section class="webdesigntuts-workshop">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID='ScriptManager1' runat='server' EnablePageMethods='true' />
    <form id="form1" runat="server">            
        <asp:TextBox type="search" name="search" id="sform" placeholder="What are you looking for?" runat="server" />       
         <asp:TextBox type="search" name="hdnText" id="hdnText" runat="server" />

        <button id="Button1"  runat="server" onclientclick="lookup();return false;">Search</button>
    </form>
</section>

</body>
```

Here is my javascript lookup.js which is placed in the Scripts folder.

```
function Signup() {
    var query = document.getElementById('<%=sform.ClientID %>').value;


    PageMethods.lookupfromjs_Click(query);

    function onSucess(result) {
        alert(result);
    }

    function onError(result) {
        alert('Cannot process your request at the moment, please try later.');
    }
}
```

here is the aspx.cs function.

```
protected void lookupfromjs_Click(String query)
        {

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
            {
                hdnText.Text = "query= " + query + " look up number " + lookup_no++;

                // sform.Text= "You are looking up the term " + query;

            }
        }
```

There are no errors as such in VS or in browser. But my breakpoints in browser dont seem to kick in. The java script is loaded correctly by the browser. However on button click nothing seems to happen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is this? 'protected void lookupfromjs_Click(String query)

Comment: AFAIK the method in aspx.cs needs to be static and also marked with `[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]`. Did you already try this?

Comment: thank you.. i missed "static"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with `.aspx` files, you are using the `webforms` framework. If you use webforms, then the normal thing to do here would be to have an `<asp:Button runat="server" ...></asp:Button>` with an event handler in the code behind page. If you want to avoid `postbacks` then you are using the wrong framework.

That said, there are of course cases where a post back is unnecessarily heavy, and you just want to run a tiny code snippet on the server. Page methods can then be used.

In order for a method in the code behind to be usable as a `page method`, the method must:

- Be decorated with the `[WebMethod]` attribute - System.Web.Services.WebMethod
- Be declared `public static`

Note that a page method is not able to work with controls on the page. A page method is called using an `ajax` request. There is not full page generation going on. Any updates to the page that is using the page method must be done using `javascript` after the method returns.

There are at least a few different apparent errors in your code:

- You call `lookup(); return false;` yet the javascript method is called `Signup`
- You have this: `<%=sform.ClientID %>` in your `lookup.js` file. But that file is brought in using a `<script ... ></script>` tag, which is a separate request by the browser, handled by a static handler. So the `<%=sform.ClientID %>` will not be resolved.
- Your *so called* web method is not correctly defined, *and* it tries to work with controls in the page as if it was a post back event handler.
- Etc

---

Working sample (works for me):

Web form:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/lookup.js") %>"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"
            EnablePageMethods="true">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:TextBox type="search" name="search" ID="sform" placeholder="What are you looking for?" runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox type="search" name="hdnText" ID="hdnText" runat="server" />
        <button id="Button1" onclick="Signup('<%= sform.ClientID %>', '<%= hdnText.ClientID %>');">Search</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
function Signup(sformId, hdnId) {
    var query = document.getElementById(sformId).value;
    var res = PageMethods.lookupfromjs_Click(query, onSucess, onError);
    function onSucess(result) {
        document.getElementById(hdnId).value = result;
        alert(result);

    }
    function onError(result) {
        alert('Cannot process your request at the moment, please try later.');
    }
}
```

Page method:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string lookupfromjs_Click(String query)
{
    return "query was " + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(query);
}
```